# xcode - UITableView dynamic Cell-/Label height

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios8

I work on a little iOS8 App with a table view. I use custom cell style, with means I heave to labels (headLabel, bodyLabel). The headLabel is usually short, but the bodyLabel can have around 30 words. How can I make a dynamic Cell (imported: also the label should have the same height like the cell). I found something, but the most are just for iOS7.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Create a UITableViewCell class and add a IBOutlet property.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface YourTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *yourLabel;

@end
```

Then, in the IB create a new cell and assign the new class you created (YourTableViewCell in this example)

[image: Create Custom UITableViewCell]

Now add a label in the IB and connect the "YourLabel" outlet.

[image: Create Custom UITableViewCell]

Then you have some options there, you can change it manually or programmatically to any value or use the default value 44. Also, if you expect the height of the rows to change dynamically use the UITableView delegate method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Thanks, but it isn`t really that, what I search for. I now, how the set up a table view, but my problem is that I don't know what 

"you have some options there, you can change it manually or programmatically to any value or use the default value 44. Also, if you expect the height of the rows to change dynamically use the UITableView delegate method tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:" 

means

Comment: For an example: How can I define the "cellForRowAtIndexPath"

Comment: Well I'm not sure if I understand, but once you set your view controller as the delegate (and datasource) for the TableView you should be able to use all the methods in the delegate, including "cellForRowAtIndexPath" . Just write those you need in the code and they'd be called when necessary.